# How to represent/aggregate data belonging to same group, and feed to model for training?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, data-cleaning, data-analysis

I have a problem in which there are couple of records that belong to the same group, like multiple observations. For example this data set

[image]

has three groups, For each group, I have three observations.
I need to find how can I represent this data as a single row or is there any way to solve this problem. 
*Note* - Suppose if one of the observations is 'Ok' then all the observation of that group becomes 'Ok'.

Comment: Can you maybe add the expected output so that we can understand better?

Comment: I don't know what should be the output or process the data,, I have the input data as in the image, need to feed for training

Comment: I am asking how should the table look? What format of table you want from the given image format?

Comment: It can be in any format, for which I can use it for model training..

Comment: Group can be considered as a feature and used with the model. Otherwise if each lines are part of a group of 3 you can consider having feature01, 02, 03, 04, 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24 ... maybee try both to check which one fits best your model / needs and give us feedback.